# How to split a data frame based on string in column within groups using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, subset, string-matching

I have a data frame, **grouped** by column "id". The data frame should be **split based on a substring** that occurs in column "alteration". The substrings I am interested in are **"intermediate"**, **"high"**, or none of the strings occurring **within a group**.

Here is a sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  disease = c("brain", "brain", "neck", "neck","breast", "breast"),
  status = c("yes", "yes","no","no","yes","yes"),
  gene = c("P53","TMB","ATM","TMB","RAF","NFKB"),
  alteration = c("TP53Y","TMB-intermediate","TATMY","TMB-high","TRAFY","TNFKBY"))
```

resulting in data frame

```
id  disease status  gene    alteration
1   brain   yes     P53     TP53Y
1   brain   yes     TMB     TMB-intermediate
2   neck    no      ATM     TATMY
2   neck    no      TMB     TMB-high
3   breast  yes     RAF     TRAFY
3   breast  yes     NFKB    TNFKBY
```

Expected output should be three data frames:

**dfIntermed**

```
id  disease status  gene    alteration
1   brain   yes P53 TP53Y
1   brain   yes TMB TMB-intermediate
```

**dfHigh**

```
id  disease status  gene    alteration
2   neck    no  ATM TATMY
2   neck    no  TMB TMB-high
```

**dfNo (this data frame contains no information about TMB within group)**

```
id  disease status  gene    alteration
3   breast  yes RAF TRAFY
3   breast  yes NFKB    TNKFBY
```

**EDIT**

Another post suggests the use of split(). When I split the data frame using the code:

```
out <- split(df, f = df$alteration )
out[[1]]
```

I get back six data frames, but I'm not able to grep the strings in f =. Is it possible to grep for 'high' or 'intermediate' within split?

**EDIT II**

I can split in combination with grep, but this returns only single rows and not the whole group

```
outB <- split(df, list(id, grepl("high", df$alteration)))
outB[[2]]
```

**EDIT III**

Issue resolved in another post

[Issue resolved in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574780/how-to-grep-a-group-based-on-string-in-another-column-that-doesnt-occur-in-each/57574974#57574974)

Comment: Look at `split()` function.

Comment: Hi tmfmnk, do you know how to grep for 'high' and 'intermediate within split? Actually this question is not a duplicate as marked by Sotos.

Comment: I think the question is not a duplicate of the linked question and and not solely solved by using `split`, as Zipfer wants to split the data frame so that observations with the same ID stay together, but where the information that the data frame is supposed to be split on is only present in one observation per ID

Comment: You can try `split(df, grepl("high", df$alteration))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk thanks, this returns only a single row containing 'high' in alteration versus the rest of the data frame.